# Why do my cheekbones hurt when I play?

Tags: practice, flute, band, health, ergonomics

I play the flute and I don’t know if it’s just me but my cheekbones hurt when I play for more the 30 minutes. I don’t know what it could be, I usually have good posture and practice everyday. I have a class (and get graded) for high school band, so it’s really not optional. What do you think it is?

Comment: While we might be able to throw out guesses, that's *all* we can do for this kind of question. If you have an instructor of some kind, this is a much better question for them than for us - we're not going to be able to diagnose the possible flaws in your playing technique, no matter how well you describe your technique. Plus, maybe it's not technique at all - in that case, maybe it's some kind of medical thing? My point is we welcome questions, but this is likely going to be unanswerable, I'm afraid. *(Also, I'm assuming it's high school band? If not, that can be fixed later)*

Comment: Bones don't usually hurt. It'll likely be cheek muscles, due to the shape you make with your embouchure. Maybe you're trying too hard. Your teacher, who can watch what you do, is your best contributor to an answer.

Comment: If you have a class, then you have a teacher.  It's a poor teacher that will mark you down for asking how to improve.  Go ask!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes band teachers are busier than a one-armed paper hanger.  Maybe a short email would help (for instance *Dear (name), do you have some time to help me work on my embouchure?  I could come in my lunch period or after school on x, y, z days*).

I found a similar question, along with a variety of answers, at [The Session](https://thesession.org/discussions/22893), a "community website dedicated to Irish traditional music":

- All embouchures are unique so it’s not so much that you’re doing  something "wrong" it’s more that you’re generating    unnecessary    tension in your face. For the first couple of months    or so, some    soreness in the small "kissing" or "smiling" muscles    around the mouth    is pretty usual but it doesn’t last for very long    after you put the    flute down. It might be that you’re "grinning"    to get your    embouchure. While looking in a mirror, you could try    experimenting    with a more neutral mouth shape i.e. the shape your    lips form in    repose, and then very gradually shape them until you
  can produce a    note.

  Another possibility, though less likely, is that you’re using your    cheeks as air pouches. If so, don’t! It’s worth remembering    that with    a efficient embouchure a flute needs no more air than a    whistle.
- I would suggest practice for a bit shorter. As soon as it    starts to feel painful, quit, but take a note of minutes    practiced.    And then the next day add on a couple of minutes,    maintain that for    few days then increase, always keeping an eye on    the clock.
- The embouchure should be tight in the corners but flexible in the    middle. Jaw and tongue should be relaxed.

  Try cutting back to 15 min or so as others suggested earlier.
- Don’t use your cheeks as bellows; building up the muscles,  etc., you may also have to investigate how you are forming the cavity inside your mouth. Your    throat should be open, that's to say, you should feel like    you’re    yawning with your mouth closed. If you’re doing this, your    cheeks    will also be relaxed although it can be infectious (yawning    as I    type).

  But don’t over do the practice, you can build up your    time    when the muscles are in a position to cooperate.
- The flute goes under your lips, not inside your mouth.